# How to use DateField in Qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I want to use the DateField from qooxdoo. I have a lot of trouble.
I downloaded the Qooxdoo desktop sdk that contains the UI package. 
I followed the instruction and successfully got the first "demo" page with the button there.

But, unfortunately, the package qx.ui.form contains only the button class and I need the DateField class.

In the docs, it shows the DateField class inside the qx.ui.form package.
So how can I finally use the DateField class?

Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you change code, you're suppose to use generate.py to compile your code sort of.